# Prevent a form from being submitted javascript why is there an obvious false statement returning true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
<script>
function someFunc() {
    if (1==2) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Not submitting");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

This is from stackoverflow here

[prevent form submission (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248576/prevent-form-submission-javascript)

I want to know what the purpose of the obvious false statement 1==2 returns true is for?

Comment: It's dummy, placeholder code. They wanted a function that would *always* return `false` (for testing); real validation code would replace `1 == 2` later.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to stop a form from submitting you would need to do two things:

- Place an "onsubmit" event on the form tag
- define the event handler in javascript and return false in that function

So, basically, in HTML you would need:

```
<form ... onsubmit="return someFunc()">
```

And in the javascript code you would need:

```
function someFunc() {
    return false;
}
```

The part with **1 == 2** its for developing purposes only i would imagine, just a mechanism of making the forms to never submit.

When moving on from the developing environment this should be done in a more clever configurable way.

You might as well have a function like this:

```
function someFunc() {
    if (1 > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Not submitting");
        return false;
    }
}
```

That validation is only meant to always stop the from from submitting.

Or, a function like this:

```
function someFunc() {
    alert("Not submitting");
    return false;
}
```